# How to check if argument is valid GUID?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, guid

In my Wix XML, I have a parameter

```
<Property Id="PRODUCT_ID" Value='NA'/>
```

Which is also backed by `<Condition>` that it must be passed (i.e. cannot be "NA"):

```
<Condition Message='Product ID is required.'>
      (not PRODUCT_ID = "NA")
</Condition>
```

However, I also need to ensure that given parameter (PRODUCT_ID) is a valid GUID? I can write up a function in a Custom DLL, and return failure from function (along with a message box from DLL's function). However, where do I call the function?

I believe, it would go under `<InstallExecuteSequence>`, but where?

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="validateGUI" Before="???"  ???/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a CA that will examine PRODUCT_ID for validness and assign a value to another property, e.g. PRODUCT_ID_OK.  Then use PRODUCT_ID_OK in the condition.

Conditions are evaluated during LaunchConditions, thus you need to run CA before that: Before="LaunchConditions"

Comment: Can't the CA function just return failure if GUID-string is not valid, instead of assigning it to another property?

Comment: How do you pass that to condition?

Comment: I'm using this: `<Custom Action="checkGUID" Before ="LaunchConditions"/>` and this: `<CustomAction Id='checkGUID' BinaryKey='myBin' DllEntry='CheckIfGUIDValid'/>`, and it fails the installation if guid is invalid.

Comment: But there is no reasonable error message for the user.

Comment: How can I give message to user out of OK variable?

Comment: It is a Message in your Condition.

Comment: Don't know how it is going to work?! Property check is done before custom function is called, hence value set (PRODUCT_ID_OK) by function has no effect.